# Left inverses, $(m-n) ^n$

Tags: inverse, function-and-relation-composition

Let f be a map from A to B. My book says that there are $(m-n)^n$ left inverses on injective mappings, where $n =|A|$ and $m = |B|$. Can someone explain why this is the case ? $m-n$ is somewhat understandable, since we are looking for all elements of $B$ which are not images of $f$. But why is it then raised to the $n$ ?

Comment: Presumably, injective functions $A\to B?$ Seems like it should be $n^{m-n}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, it's a mapping, not a function, made an error

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Would that matter though, that it's a mapping? Or it's still $n^{m-n}$?

Comment: What is the difference between a mapping and a function? Same thing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you! That clears up some confusion for sure. Then, why is it $n^{m-n}$, from a combinatorial perspective? As in how is each new mapping arranged, as m grows?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews And also, what would the formula for number of right inverses of a surjective map be? $n^{n-m}$?

Comment: @JohnDoe nope, for right inverses if surjectives, you have to pick for each $y$ some $x$ as image with $f(x)=y$, and the number of available choices for $x$ may differ with $y$ and strongly depends on details of $f$. So there is no such “dual” formula